# How to get single value in react-select dropdown

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I am trying to create a multi-select dropdown indicator [(the second element shown here)](https://react-select.com/home) using react-select.

The purpose is to show all blog post categories on a blog page, and then to only render the blog posts that are selected in the dropdown indicator.

The tags are extracted from their posts based on a GraphQL query and stored in useState variables "tags" and "renderedPosts".

**How do I simply get a value from the dropdown when a category is added or removed?** Reading the react-select API, I get this:

```
getValue () => ReadonlyArray<...>
```

I don't know how to use that, VS Code simply screams when I try add an arrow function as an attribute in the Select.

I understand there is supposed to be a "value" by default on the Select but if I try to use it I get undefined.

I don't know if mapping to the default value is a problem or if it has anything to do with the ContextProvider (which was necessary). There are other attributes I cannot get to work either, like maxMenuHeight (which is supposed to take a number).

Allow me to share my code (you can probably ignore the useEffect):

```
export default function Blog({ data }) {
    const { posts } = data.blog

    const [tags, setTags] = useState([])
    const [renderedPosts, setRenderedPosts] = useState([])

    // Context necessary to render default options in react-select
    const TagsContext = createContext();

    // setting all tags (for dropdown-indicator) and rendered posts below the dropdown (initially these two will be the same)
    useEffect(() => {
        const arr = [];
        data.blog.posts.map(post => {
            post.frontmatter.tags.map(tag => {
                if (!arr.some(index => index.value === tag)) {
                    arr.push({ value: tag, label: tag })
                }
            })
        });
        setTags([arr]);
        setRenderedPosts([arr]);
    }, []);

    function changeRenderedPosts(value???){
        setRenderedPosts(value???)
    }

    return (
        <Layout>
            <div>
                <h1>My blog posts</h1>
                <TagsContext.Provider value={{ tags }}>
                    <Select
                        defaultValue={tags.map(tag => tag) }
                        isMulti
                        name="tags"
                        options={tags}
                        className="basic-multi-select"
                        classNamePrefix="select"
                        // HOW DO I PASS THE VALUE OF THE ADDED/DELETED OPTION?
                        onChange={() => changeRenderedPosts(value???)}
                        maxMenuHeight= {1}
                    />
                </TagsContext.Provider>
                // posts to be rendered based on renderedPosts value
                {posts.map(post => {
```

EDIT: The closest I have now come to a solution is the following:

```
   function changeRenderedTags(options){
        console.log(options) //logs the remaining options
        setRenderedTags(options) //blocks the change of the dropdown elements
    }

    return (
        <Layout>
            <div>
                <h1>My blog posts</h1>
                <TagsContext.Provider value={{ tags }}>
                    <Select
                      ...
                        onChange={(tagOptions) => changeRenderedTags(tagOptions)}
```

I click to delete one option from the dropdown and I get the other two options in "tagOptions". But then if I try to change "renderedTags", the update of the state is blocked. I find this inexplicable as "setRenderedTags" has nothing to do with the rendering of the dropdown or its data!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it - I don't know if it is the best solution but it really works! Sharing it here in case anyone else is in the exact same situation, or if you are just curious. Constructive criticism is welcome.

```
export default function Blog({ data }) {
    const { posts } = data.blog

    const [tags, setTags] = useState([])
    const [renderedTags, setRenderedTags] = useState([])

    const TagsContext = createContext();

    useEffect(() => {
        const arr = [];
        posts.map(post => {
            post.frontmatter.tags.map(tag => {
                if (!arr.some(index => index.value === tag)) {
                    arr.push({ value: tag, label: tag })
                }
            })
        });
        setTags([...arr]);
    }, [posts]);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        setRenderedTags([...tags]);
    }, [tags])

    return (
        <Layout>
            <div>
                <h1>My blog posts</h1>
                <TagsContext.Provider value={{ tags }}>
                    <Select
                        defaultValue={tags}
                        isMulti
                        name="tags"
                        options={tags}
                        className="basic-multi-select"
                        classNamePrefix="select"
                        onChange={(tagOptions) => setRenderedTags(tagOptions ? tagOptions.map(option => option) : [])}
                        value={renderedTags}
                    />
                </TagsContext.Provider>
                {posts.map(post => 
                    (post.frontmatter.tags.some(i => renderedTags.find(j => j.value === i))) ? 
                    
                        <article key={post.id}>
                            <Link to={post.fields.slug}>
                                <h2>{post.frontmatter.title}</h2>
                                <p>{post.frontmatter.introduction}</p>
                            </Link>
                            <small>
                                {post.frontmatter.author}, {post.frontmatter.date}
                            </small>
                            <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: post.html }} />
                        </article>
                    
                    : null 
                )}
            </div>
        </Layout>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

with `isMulti` option true, you get array of options(here it's `tags`) from onChange callback. so I guess you could just set new tags and render filtered posts depending on the selected tags like below?

```
const renderedPosts = posts.filter(post => post.tags.some(tag => tags.includes(tag)))

...
onChange={selectedTags => {
  setTags(selectedTags ? selectedTags.map(option => option.value) : [])
}}
...
```

Comment: Your second line doesn't quite work as it causes the tags in the dropdown to lose their values if I remove one of them. Changing to option => option fixes this, but the other problem is that it is no longer possible to add tags again - the actual dropdown is empty. Your code is a start nonetheless, thanks.

Comment: Not solved yet, though perhaps close. Updated my initial post with an "EDIT" at the end.

Comment: onChange returns undefined if dropdown has no selected options.
so you can add condition for that. I updated code

Comment: The dropdown has always had selected options, so this does not change anything (except perhaps in some other edge cases). No, if I try to run setTags() like this, it removes the values of remaining items and then if I try to add them back again, when I open the dropdown I get: "Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'options' in [my category]"

I feel a bit stuck here because there seems to be a lot of magic going on behind the scenes and I don't know how to debug it.